# How to transform a Pandas Dataframe with splitted value from a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame with specific Codes (MeSH Codes) which i need to transform in a way, that i can visualize the path to s next higher MeSH Code.

My input DataFrame looks like this:

```
Example = pd.DataFrame({"source":["C23.550.291.125","E01.370.225.998.054.119","E04.074.119"]})
```

In this Example, my Output DataFrame should have 16 rows looking something like this:

- C23.550.291.125
- C23.550.291
- C23.550
- C23
- ...

I hope someone can decifer my horrible formatted question. I just started programming and even stackoverflow questions are hard for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very pretty, but I think it will do

```
import pandas as pd

Example = pd.DataFrame({"source":["C23.550.291.125","E01.370.225.998.054.119","E04.074.119"]})

array_result = []
for col in Example["source"].str.split("."):
    result = ""
    for row in col:
        if result:
            result+="."
        result += f"{row}"
        array_result.append({'response': result}) 

df_result = pd.DataFrame(array_result)
print(df_result)
```

**#Example response:**

[image]

**#update**

```
import pandas as pd
Example = pd.DataFrame({"source":["C23.550.291.125","E01.370.225.998.054.119","E04.074.119"]})


array_result = []
for rows in Example["source"]:
    col = rows.split(".")
    result = ""
    for row in col:
        if result:
            result+="."
        result += f"{row}"
        array_result.append({'response': result, "root": rows}) 

df_result = pd.DataFrame(array_result)
print(df_result)
```

**#Example response:**

[image]

Comment: is it possible to convert the result in a way, that the root code is represented n times in another column? So that the result looks like this: Example = pd.DataFrame({"source":["C23.550.291","C23.550","C23"],"root":["C23.550.291.125","C23.550.291.125","C23.550.291.125"]})